# Please explain this long sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

From *Begegnungen B1,* Kapitel 1:

> Es gibt Leute, die bei eBay einen Koffer für den Urlaub kaufen wollen und nach vier Stunden im Internet Besitzer eines Autos sind, obwohl sie gar keinen Führerschein haben.

I understand that it says:

> There are people who want to buy a suitcase for holiday and four hours later on the Internet (there are) car owners although they don’t have driving licenses.

It’s really confusing what it's trying to say.

Comment: How do you get to the part in parentheses? That’s where you went wrong.

Comment: @CarstenS I think the asker thought it could be a parallelism: *es gibt Leute, die X, und [Leute,] die Y*, although that would at least require a comma and a second relative pronoun: *... wollen, und die ...*. As it is, it's not working this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it almost right except for the part in parentheses:

> There are people who want to buy a suitcase for holiday and four hours
>   later on the Internet they are car owners although they don’t even have
>   a driving license.

It's trying to say that people tend to buy things they don't really need.

Comment: *buy things they don't really need* instead of the things they are looking for.